# Is there a ways i can update @RequestParam from java script in regards to what user <form:options> selected?

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, jsp, jstl

My goal is: update the @RequestParam id from a jsp file, when user select an item from form:select

I wast able to include the countries and states from my api into the select form type. See code below:

```
@GetMapping("/addForm")
public String addForm(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam(defaultValue = "1") Long cId){

        model.addAttribute("countryList", countryService.getCountry());
        model.addAttribute("stateList", countryService.getCountryState(cId));
        model.addAttribute("cId", cId);

        return "vehicle";
}
```

My jsp

```
<c:url var="stateLink" value="/vehicle/addForm">
    <c:param name="cId" value='${cId}'/>
</c:url>

//inside a form 
 <div class="form-group row" id="countryChoice">
   <form:select class="form-control" path="country" >
   <form:options  items="${countryList}" itemValue="countryName" itemLabel="countryName"/>

   </form:select>
</div>

<div class="form-group row" >
  <form:select class="form-control" path="state">
     <form:options items="${stateList}" itemValue="stateName" itemLabel="stateName"/>
   </form:select>
</div>
```

when user check the country option and select Australia, i want to set ${cId} to 1 and ${stateLink} clickable from the form:options, 2 if NZ, 3 if UK. To be able to get it in the controller and populate the required states for each selected country.

I tried hard to get this working, but no luck!! Any easy solution using jQuery or jsp much appreciated !